# Drawing WriteableBitmap that changes

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap

I have a controller class that returns some images as `WriteableBitmap`. I use that lib in my `WPF` app that should refresh the `Image` immediately. The problem is, nothing happens when I change its `Source` :/

```
private void Csm_OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
   WriteableBitmap bitmap = ((Csm) sender).Bitmap;
   Preview.Source = bitmap;
}
```

How to change the code inside to refresh the image? Sometimes event occurs about 10-20 times for second, so it works almost like video preview.

Comment: A stupid question, but have you verified that the bitmap returned is actually valid?

Comment: Why stupid? The control doesn't refresh when I change the source so I wanna know why and how to correct this. Btw. `Preview` is a WPF `Image` control. Yes, it is valid.

Comment: It was stupid because, you probably checked it already. but the next question is what type is `((Csm)sender).Bitmap` a bitmap or a writeable bitmap?

Comment: I know that the bitmap is good, because I saved some PNG files to check it. But it doesn't work when I want to display it in `Image` control.

Comment: Instead of creating an intermediate WriteableBitmap, try assigning your ((Csm)sender).Bitmap directly to it see what happens then